# Integration: a typical question

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If $f(x)$ is a *differentiable function* such that $f(x)=(1+\frac{x^3}{3})$+$(\int _0^{x}\:{e^{-t}f(x-t)}dt)$.Then what is the value of $\int _0^{1}\:f(x)dx$?

Okay so the first part is okay and easily doable but how do I integrate the second part? Do I use integration by parts? Also Im told lebniz rule can be applied in such questions. Could you help?

Comment: How many questions you asked today ? Unless you show your attempts, you'll get down-votes. This is not a place where others do your homework or test problems.

Comment: Asking questions is what this site is about right?

Comment: It is. Yes. But you have to show some progress. Look at the number of down-votes.

Comment: Okay so I did specify what my problem is really.. So please remove your downvote now

Answer (score 1):

We differentiate the function and also using [Leibniz rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), we get: $$f'(x) = x^2 + (e^{-x}f(0)-0)$$ We know that the value of $f(0) = 1+0 +\int_{0}^{0} e^{-t}f(-t) dt = 1 + 0 + 0 = 1$. So thus, $$f'(x) = x^2 + e^{-x}$$ Now, integrate this to get $f(x)$ and do the necessary. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Zlatan It is much more easier to proceed it that way. See the function becomes simple. I find double integrating it not very feasible. And that is why I also provided you the Wiki link to the rule.

Comment: Good, good and how did you differentiate the second part? Knowing the technique to do that made you figure out to use leibniz. So please tell me the procedure to differentiate the second part.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Just integrate as usual. First term on the right hand side should be OK. For the second term do a change of order of integration. Sketching a region will be helpful.

Comment: How do I get that second part done!?